# Interchange of a limit and integral

Tags: integration, limits

How would one show the following equality? Trying standard convergence theorems eg DCT (I can't find a choice of a dominating function which is also integrable) do not appear to be successful.

$$\lim_{a_n \to 0^+} \int_\mathbb{R} e^{−a_n|x|}\frac {\sin(x)}x dx=\int_\mathbb{R} \frac {\sin(x)}x dx $$

Thanks

Comment: The function $x \mapsto {\sin x \over x}$ is not integrable in the usual sense. It is an improper Lebesgue or Riemann integral.

Comment: In other words, before we can try to prove the asserted equality, we need to have a precise definition of the integral on the right-hand side. What do you think it means? Is it, for example, a Cauchy principal value?

Comment: If I may recommend some general background to this, take a look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sinc_function

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With $a > 0$ we have

$$\int_{\mathbb{R}}e^{-a|x|} \frac{\sin x}{x} \, dx = 2 \int_0^\infty e^{-ax} \frac{\sin x}{x} \, dx, $$

and it is enough to consider the limit of the integral on the RHS.

In that case, we want to show that

$$\tag{*}\lim_{a \to 0+}\int_0^\infty e^{-ax} \frac{\sin x}{x} \, dx = \int_0^\infty \lim_{a \to 0+}e^{-ax} \frac{\sin x}{x} \, dx = \int_0^\infty \frac{\sin x}{x} \, dx = \frac{\pi}{2}$$

We can switch the limit and the integral as long as the improper integral is unformly convergent for $a \geqslant 0$.  To prove this, note that for any $c > 0$

$$\tag{**}\left|\int_0^\infty e^{-ax} \frac{\sin x}{x} \, dx  - \int_0^\infty  \frac{\sin x}{x} \, dx    \right| \\ \leqslant \left|\int_0^c e^{-ax} \frac{\sin x}{x} \, dx  - \int_0^c  \frac{\sin x}{x} \, dx    \right| + \left|\int_c^\infty e^{-ax} \frac{\sin x}{x} \, dx      \right| + \left|\int_c^\infty  \frac{\sin x}{x} \, dx      \right| $$

Since the integrand is uniformly continuous for $(x,a) \in [0,c] \times [0,b]$ for any $b > 0$, there exists $\delta > 0$ such that the first term on the RHS is less than $\epsilon/3$ when $0 < a <\delta$.  This, of course, is the justification for switching the limit and integral over a bounded interval.  By uniform convergence of the improper integral of $e^{-ax} \sin x / x$ and the convergence of the improper integral of $\sin x /x$, there exists $c > 0$ independent of $a$ such that second and third terms on the RHS are each less than $\epsilon/3$ as well.

To confirm uniform convergence -- for any $c_2 > c_1 > 0$ we have by the second mean value theorem for integrals the existence of a point $\xi$ with $c_1 < \xi < c_2$ such that

$$\left|\int_{c_1}^{c_2} e^{-ax} \frac{\sin x}{x} \, dx \right| = \frac{e^{-ac_1}}{c_1}\left|\int_{c_1}^{\xi}\sin x \, dx \right| = \frac{e^{-ac_1}}{c_1}\left|\cos c_1 - \cos \xi\right| \leqslant \frac{2}{c_1}$$

Now the RHS is smaller than $\epsilon >0$ by choosing $c_1 > 2/ \epsilon$ for any $a \geqslant 0$ and, by the Cauchy criterion, the improper integral is uniformly convergent, Therefore (*) is true.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't follow when you say we can switch the limit and the integral as long as the improper integral is unformly convergent. Isn't the integral just a numeric value as a function of a?

Comment: As you say the integral is of the form $F(a)= \int_0^\infty f(x,a) \, dx$ and we are trying to show that $\lim_{a \to 0+} F(a) = F(0) = \int_0^\infty f(x,0) \, dx$. This is equivalent to switching the limit with the integral, since $\lim_{a \to 0+} f(x,a) = f(x,0)$.  To prove this we have to show that the LHS of (**) can be made smaller than any $\epsilon >0$ when $0 < a < \delta$ where $\delta$ varies only with $\epsilon$. It is a basic theorem that for an integral of $f(x,a)$ on a bounded interval  where the integrand is continuous  we can take the limit as $a \to 0+$ inside the integral.

Comment: The approach is to pick a $c > 0$ and show there is such a $\delta$ such that if $0 < a < \delta$, then the RHS of (**) is less than $\epsilon$.  This is accomplished by using the limit/integral switching result  for the first term on the RHS when $c$ is fixed, after picking $c$ such that the second and third terms are small -- and to do this for the second term, $c$ can't vary with $a$ -- requiring uniform convergence of the improper integral $\int_0^\infty f(x,a) \, dx$ for $a > 0$.

Comment: More generally, this is a basic result proved in most real analysis books that $F(a) = \int_0^\infty f(x,a) \, dx$ is continuous at $a_0$ when the integral converges uniformly and $f$ is continuous on $[0,\infty) \times I$ where $I$ is an interval containing $a_0$.

Comment: Now I'm guessing you don't fully understand what it means for an improper integral to be uniformly convergent. You need to understand that for this to make sense.  We say the improper integral $F(a) = \int_0^\infty f(x,a) \, dx$ is uniformly convergent for $a \geqslant 0$ if for every $\epsilon > 0$ there exists $K(\epsilon) > 0$ such that $\left|\int_0^c f(x,a) \, dx - F(a)\right| < \epsilon$ for all $c > K(\epsilon)$ and for all $a \geqslant 0$. If $K$ depended on $a$, the integral could converge pointwise w/r $a$ but not uniformly.

Comment: Thank you for the further explanation. I think I'm able to understand your answer now.